# Fork Infinite Loop

Tags: c, exec, fork, infinite-loop

I am trying to make an directory monitoring program in C. So far it detects the  subdirectories of a main directory, however the problem happens when I try to monitor the subdirectories of the subdirectories.

```
char * const  son[] = { argv[0], name, NULL };  

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    execvp(son[0], son);
}
```

This code should have created a child process which would monitor the subdirectories. `name` is a string with the subdirectory "Desktop/test", for example. 
I tried to print "name" before and it is the subdirectory I want so the problem isn't here.

The program works flawlessly until I add this. Once I add it, it enters an infinite loop, despite working previously. I also want to point out I don't use signals so the problem doesn't come from them.

### This of course is just an excerpt of he code. If you think I need to post the full code, which is much bigger, I will add it, although honestly I doubt the problem is in it since it worked perfectly before.

EDIT:
Better add all the code, argv[1] is the directory,argv[2] for how many minutes I want the program to run, argv[3], it's the pause between each scan. It works if I remove the excerpt above and I know it's a bit confusing but if you have any questions just say.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


char** direc;
int direct_pos = 0;
direc = (char**) malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));


double actual_time = 0;
double MAXTIME = atof(argv[2]);
MAXTIME = MAXTIME * 60;
double IterationTime = atof(argv[3]);
time_t start = time(0);


char dot2[100];
char dot[100];

sprintf(dot, "%s/.", argv[1]); 
sprintf(dot2, "%s/..", argv[1]); 
direct_pos++;
direc[direct_pos - 1] = (char*) malloc(strlen(dot) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(direc[direct_pos - 1], dot);
direct_pos++;
direc[direct_pos - 1] = (char*) malloc(strlen(dot2) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(direc[direct_pos - 1], dot2);
if (argc != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s dir_name\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
while (actual_time < MAXTIME) {
    DIR *dirp;

    if ((dirp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(2);
    }

    struct stat stat_buf;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        char name[100];
        sprintf(name, "%s/%s", argv[1], direntp->d_name);   
        if (lstat(name, &stat_buf) == -1)  
        {

            perror("lstat ERROR");
            exit(3);
        }

        if (S_ISDIR(stat_buf.st_mode)) 
                      {

            int x;
            for (x = 0; x <= direct_pos; x++) {

                if (x == direct_pos) {

                    char**newarray;
                    newarray = (char**) malloc((direct_pos + 1)* sizeof(char*));
                    int l;
                    for (l = 0; l < direct_pos; l++) {
                                            //printf("\nxxxx%d\n", sizeof(direc[l]));

                        newarray[l] = (char*) malloc((strlen(direc[l])+1)
                                * sizeof(char));


                        strcpy(newarray[l], direc[l]);
                    }

                    direc = newarray;

                    direc[direct_pos] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(name)
                            * sizeof(char));
                    direc[direct_pos] = strcpy(direc[direct_pos], name);
                    direct_pos++;

                    double seconds_since_start = difftime(time(0), start);
                    double new_time = (MAXTIME - seconds_since_start) / 60;
                    char time_array[10];

                                          sprintf(time_array,"%f",new_time);

                    char * const  son[] = { argv[0], name, time_array,
                            argv[3], NULL };




           printf("\n%s\n",son[1]);
    x = direct_pos + 2;     
            pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
         execvp(son[0], son)==-1);
                      break;
                             }

                } else if (strcmp(name, direc[x]) == 0) {

                    x = direct_pos + 2;
                }
            }

        }



    }

    sleep(IterationTime);
    actual_time += IterationTime;
    closedir(dirp);
}

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Post more code. How do you read args in main?

Comment: @pajton Sorry, I didn't mean to edit out your tags.  I think I started editing before you submitted your edit but I submitted mine after.

Comment: @yetti no problem, I am not the owner of the post:)

Answer (score 2):

You have a program that forks and then runs a new copy of itself. Think of it as endless recursion. There's no need to exec a new instance, simply write your code so that the program continues down one of two paths depending on the returned process ID.

But that's not the correct solution.

The correct solution is not to fork at all. You gain almost no benefit from having a thousand processes that look at one directory, versus a single process that looks at a thousand directories. Actually, you may be far worse, by putting load on the scheduler.

Comment: It's an exercise where I must use fork, there is no way around that.

Comment: Agreed and furthermore, manual polling of the directories isn't necessary at all if using Linux (see `inotify(7)` in the manpages).

Comment: @user697110 - ok, you have to use `fork()`, but you don't have to use `exec()`. In fact, the exercise is probably trying to teach you how to write forked programs to properly handle both parent and child.

Comment: But then how do I enter the subdirectory, to monitor if there is anything in it?

Comment: @user697110 - the first thing that comes to my mind is a recursive method that contains both the `readdir` and the `fork`, and maintains a list of directories that have already been forked. But, to be honest, the problem isn't terribly interesting to me, and your code is a mess, so how you solve the problem is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you always fork no matter what. I would put a check in there to make sure that if you have no subdirectories in the current directory that you don't fork.

Answer (score 0):

You are forking a child-process, but what does the parent process do after the call to `fork()?`  It seems you are wanting to recursively fork processes, but in order for that to work properly, you will have to-do the following:

1) Check to see if there are any sub-directories in the current directory ... if there aren't any, then `exit()`, otherwise read all the sub-directories in the current directory.

2) For each sub-directory fork a process.  If the fork is the child (i.e., `pid == 0`), then make a call to `execvp()`.

3) If `pid != 0`, then you're in the parent process.  Rather than trying to sleep for some period of time, make a call to `wait()`, and keep on repeating the call to `wait()` until there are no child processes left.

4) Once there are no child-processes left (i.e., `wait()` returns an error status such that `errno == ECHILD`), then you can make a call to `exit()` in the parent process.

So if you follow those 4 steps, you should not incurr any infinite loops.  Every child process will at some point exit once they reach a directory with no more sub-directories, and every parent will wait for it's children before exiting so you won't end up with any orphaned processes.  If you do end up with an infinite loop, then it's because a child process is not exiting, which would then point to the logic used to detect if there are any sub-directories in the current directory, or you're not properly detecting that there are no longer any child left to wait for in a parent process.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: It's pretty much what I did, only didn't put the waits, gonna try it now.

Comment: You don't need to make the call to `sleep()` though ... you only need the call to `wait()`. You could do something like: `while(wait(NULL) != -1 || errno != ECHILD);`. That would wait for all the spawned child processes to complete, and then would exit the while-loop.